# How to calculate running sums that conditionally reset on certain rows with 1 formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a time series representing transactions such as in [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jm5p7v9O8WgIG7tMUAfjO9veAOM7MQXSK-Vw_USnTZo/edit?usp=sharing).

I wish to have running sums on column C but reset from time to time based on column D: whenever a row in column D has non-blank, non-zero value, the running sum starting next row should reset.

For visual, the desired effect is in column E.

I can see how to achieve the effect when iterating the formula over all cells. Namely, starting with 2nd row of data, manually "drag" `=sum(C$2:C3)-sumproduct(C$2:C3,D$2:D3)`.

However, the data will be ported from an external source that is evolving all the time -- ie. the data has a dynamic number of rows. With that, I am interested in centralizing the formula to a single cell.

(Think of the manual flag in the example sheet as derived from some other parts of the sheet, which would be automatic in actual application.)

But how does one do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have an option with SCAN: it sums cumulatively until the previous value in D is non empty (that's the offset use), then it restarts from `c` value again.

The first part of the formula "hides" the remaining values when D is empty:

```
=INDEX(IF(D2:D="","", 
  SCAN(0,C2:C, LAMBDA(a,c, 
 IF(OFFSET(c,-1,1)="",a+c,c)))
            ))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. May I suggest `=INDEX(IF(isblank(D3:D),,if(D3:D,   SCAN(0,C3:C, LAMBDA(a,c,  IF(OR(isblank(OFFSET(c,-1,1)),not(OFFSET(c,-1,1))),a+c,c))),            )))` in order to continue the running sum if the marker is 0 or false? That said, my version doesn't work for the first block because the header is a text and `not()` won't accept it as input and Google Sheet `or()` does not short-circuit in syntax checks and thus cannot use `istext()` alone. Not sure how to get around it except to add a hidden helper 2nd row

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite lost with your needs, probably my English doesn't help. You need to keep the count running if column D is 0 or False? To be hidden too? `=INDEX(IF((D2:D="")+(D2:D=0),"", 
  SCAN(0,C2:C, LAMBDA(a,c, 
 IF(OR(OFFSET(c,-1,1)="",OFFSET(c,-1,1)=0),a+c,c)))
            ))` I added this to ignore 0s, can do the same with False. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes. And you are getting it perfectly, thank you! Indeed, I'd like to keep count running if column D is 0 or false. I ran into difficulty earlier because I didn't think to check text content but only thought to treat it as a boolean. Would you like to make the addition to your answer? (My question did ask for ignoring `0` or `false`. So it's best to mention it in case other ppl see it.) If you like, with your permission, I can add it to your answer as well.

Comment: It's OK, I'm glad it was useful. I was showing you the way, Add `=INDEX(IF((D2:D="")+(D2:D=0)+(D2:D=FALSE),"",    SCAN(0,C2:C, LAMBDA(a,c,   IF(OR(OFFSET(c,-1,1)="",OFFSET(c,-1,1)=0,OFFSET(c,-1,1)=FALSE),a+c,c)))             ))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in cell F2:

`=LAMBDA(groups,MAP(groups,D2:D,LAMBDA(group,label,IF(label="",,SUM(FILTER(C2:C,groups=group))))))(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({0;MAP(D2:D,LAMBDA(_,COUNTIF(D2:_,"<>")))},ROWS(D2:D),1))`

First, we assign a number to each group by doing a running count of non-blank cells:

`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({0;MAP(D2:D,LAMBDA(_,COUNTIF(D2:_,"<>")))},ROWS(D2:D),1)`

We could also use something like this:

`QUERY({0;SCAN(,D2:D,LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))},"limit "&ROWS(D2:D))`

Then we use MAP-FILTER to filter each group and SUM it:

`MAP(groups,LAMBDA(group,SUM(FILTER(C2:C,groups=group))))`

The `IF(label="",,...)` is there to display a blank cell if the corresponding D column (label) is blank.